# Jquery Image Change on SlideToggle Function

Tags: jquery, onclick, src

I have a function that is an onclick for a div. I want to change the arrow image next to the title that opens and closes the div on click. I have a function written out, and it will work to change the image from down (default) to right, but it wont change it back.

Here is the Javascript:

```
$("#toggle1").click(function () {
    $("#content").slideToggle("fast");

    if ($("#image1").attr('src', "images/arrow_down.gif")) {
        $("#image1").attr(
            'src', 
            $("#image1").attr('src').replace('_down', '_right')
        );
    } else {
        $("#image1").attr(
            'src', 
            $("#image1").attr('src').replace('_right', '_down')
        );
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center;"><a class="header" id="toggle1">Location</a>
<img id="image1" src="images/arrow_down.gif" alt="" />          
<div id="content">
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($("#image1").attr('src', "images/arrow_down.gif"))
```

needs to be

```
if ($("#image1").attr('src') == "images/arrow_down.gif")
```

Answer (score 2):

Joseph gave you your answer, but also consider the following code improvement:

```
$("#toggle1").click(function () {
    $("#content").slideToggle("fast");

    var down = $("#image1").attr('src') == "images/arrow_down.gif"

    $("#image1").attr(
        'src', 
        $("#image1").attr('src').replace(down ? '_down' : '_right', down ? '_right' : '_down')
    );
});
```

Much more compact!

Comment: I appreciate all of the help. 

I used the following:

Comment: Same as my comment below, it replaced the initial image from down to right, but it wouldn't go back

Comment: I got this to work perfectly. Thank you. It helps if I don't upload the new aspx file to the images folder :$

Comment: Kevin, if this helped you, please vote the post up and mark it as the answer via the checkmark on the left.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` returns the jQuery object on which it was called (thus providing chainability). You seem to think it returns a boolean depending on the value of the attribute.

However, maybe you don't need to test the attribute value at all. Try something like:

```
$("#toggle1").click(function() {
    var $content = $("#content");
    $("#image1").attr("src", "images/arrow_"
        + ($content.is(":visible") ? "down" : "right") + ".gif");
    $content.slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the input. I used the following:

 $("#toggle1").click(function () {
                        $("#content").slideToggle("fast");
                        var down = $("#image1").attr('src') == "images/arrow_down.gif";
                        $("#image1").attr('src', $("#image1").attr('src').replace(down ? '_down' : '_right', down ? '_right' : '_down'));
                    });

And I had the same result (image change from down to right, but wouldn't change back)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a jsfiddle... works for you something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FsDTR/)???

Comment: Using CSS is also a good option. I understand how you did it, but what confuses me, is once the button is clicked once, and the class is changed to btnToggleShow, what changes it back to btnToggleHide?